# Get id of an element, remove last 3 characters and save in another variable

Tags: jquery

I want to get the id of an element when the user hovers it, then remove the last 3 characters of it and add a "#" at the front of it and save it another variable:

```
<a href="#" id="bosstab"></a>

$(".brands li a").mouseenter(function() {
var selected_tab = $(this).attr('id');
});
```

For the above example the variable would save this in it #boss, as it removes the last 3 characters "tab" and adds the "#" at the beginning.

Thanks!

Comment: It would be more simple if your IDs get some separating character to split on as '-' or '_' but you can still use .substring() method. Question: where are you stuck?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use substring

```
var selected_tab = $(this).attr('id');
var boss = selected_tab.substring(0, selected_tab.length - 3);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var selected_tab = '#' + this.id.slice(0, -3);    
// var selected_tab = '#' + this.id.replace('tab', '');
```

Comment: Got it 10 seconds before I did ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$(".brands li a").mouseover(function() {
    var selected_tab =  '#' + $(this).attr('id').slice(0,-3);
});
```